# why is python tkinter module unable to find file even though there is one?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

so I know you might have read similar questions but my question is just a bit different, I use python 3.8.3 and I know python basics so I wanted to start using GUI, I started off with Tkinter. I had written a small program which does nothing I was just trying but it doesn't work I don't know why. It gives error that unable to find file, I tried doing the code people told in other questions but it doesn't work, probably due to python versions, here is my code:

```
from tkinter import  *

window= Tk()
window.title("first GUI program of mine")
window.configure(background="black")

photo1 = PhotoImage(file="images.jpg")
Label (window, text="1 or 2 ? :", bg="black", fg="white", font="calibri 12 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)


windows.mainloop()
```

so when I run this I get error like this:

```
tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "images.jpg": no such file or directory
```

the file is in the same folder in which the python program is saved.

any ideas?

Comment: use this: `image = Image.open("images.jpg")` `photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)`

Comment: thx for the program but i got this new error when i try it, it's this:
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: As the error said, the image cannot be found in *current directory* (it may not be the same directory of the python script).  Use `print(os.getcwd())` to show the *current directory* and see whether it is what you expect.  Also, JPG is not supported by  `tkinter.PhotoImage()`.  Use `Pillow` module instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your working directory? I think it's the problem of directory. If it's under the same level of directory, maybe you could try this: '/images.jpg'

Comment: umm so what should i show? should i copy the whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

PhotoImage class only supports GIF, PGM, PPM formats. So try to convert it.

Comment: ok i will try by changing extension, btw i tried it before it did not work

Comment: ok it gave same error again: AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: the only thing which happens is the tkinter window opens, it is full of black colour background, just for informing that when i delete code for image it works.

Comment: check out this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/basics-for-displaying-image-in-tkinter-python. I hope it helps

Comment: thaks alot it helped but it did not actually perform all operations i wanted................ 

just a request can u tell me how to resize the window through the program i typed in Q instead of the new program u told? cuz actually that new program doesn't allow me to rename the window title

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me

```
from tkinter import  *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window= Tk()
window.title("first GUI program of mine")
window.configure()

photo1 = Image.open('images.jpeg')
photo1.show()

Label(window, text="1 or 2 ? :", bg="black", fg="white", font="calibri 12 bold").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

And where do you want the image to be shown? To show the image use show() function.

Comment: ok i will try,

errrrr the module messed up.................

Comment: there is no module found it says :(
i have been facing this problem from long time

Comment: Did you have all modules installed? Use pip to install PIL module.

Comment: how do i?? i just started using GUI and tkinter i have no idea how to

Comment: idk how to  install modules, if u can pls tell

Comment: I use Jetbrains Pycharm. Here how to do it https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: i have their pycharm, ok so i will try in pycharm